# Formatting text for output - Error: "Undefined is null or not an object" - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, textarea, string-formatting

I am writing a program that will take the contents of a text area, pull out the important info, format it and then output it.

I have successfully made my program pass all the info into an array.

Currently I am working on getting the program to identify where the customer's name is located (it will always be between "Name" and either "Details" or "Customer" if "Details" is not in the correct location in the array.

```
// Parse the input box into an array
var inputArr = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.split(/[\s]/);

// Instantiate variables
var custDet, contactName, phone, companyName, email;

// Pull out all strings between "Name" and "Email" ("Card" should always be after "Email" or else it's the wrong string
if(inputArr[inputArr.indexOf("Email") + 1] == "Card") {
    custDet = inputArr.slice(inputArr.indexOf("Name") + 1, inputArr.indexOf("Email"));  

    // Pass the customer's name into the string contactName
    for(i = 0; custDet[i] != "Details" || custDet[i] != "Customer" || i < custDet.length; i++) {
        if(custDet[i].search(",") != -1) {
            var temp = custDet[i].split(/[,]/);
            temp.reverse();
            contactName = contactName + temp.join(" ");
        }
    }
    contactName = contactName + custDet.join(" ");
} else {
    contactName = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Contact Name. Please input Contact Name.");
    phone = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Contact Phone Number. Please input Contact Phone Number.");
    companyName = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Company Name. Please input Company Name.");
    email = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Email Address. Please input Email Address.");
}
```

The error is being thrown on...

```
if(custDet[i].search(",") != -1) {
```

And I don't understand why. Any help with my logic would also be appreciated.

Thank you all. :)

Comment: Have you checked to see whether `custDet[i]` might be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error likely means that you tried to reference item `i` of `custDet`, but `custDet` didn't have that many elements in it.

Your for loop is "non-standard":

```
for(i = 0; custDet[i] != "Details" || custDet[i] != "Customer" || i < custDet.length; i++)
```

and I suspect that's the source of the problem.  `i` becomes higher than `custDet.length`, so that means `custDet[i]` returns undefined.  Since `undefined != "Details"` is true, the loop keeps going past `custDet.length`.

Comment: Yeah. I was afraid of that. I don't know how to check for everything without creating a bunch of individual for loops. :(

Comment: @Mrow Put the length check as the first condition, then `&&` that with the rest. i.e. `i < custDet.length && (custDet[i] != "Details" || custDet[i] != "Customer")`

Comment: Ohhh. Alright, thank you! :) I guess I need to do more research on "non-standard" loops

Comment: Well, you have the basic idea right, you just have to be careful with the implementation.  Something like `(custDet[i] != undefined && (custDet[i] != "Details" custDet[i] != "Customer")) || i < custDet.length` would have worked too.

Comment: @Mrow Your condition still doesn't make much sense to me though, could you describe in words what you are going for?

Comment: I'll keep toying with it. I know all the values to watch out for. As long as i < custDet.length is the first condition I should be okay. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Sure. The name of the customer is always going to be in the array between the string "Name" and "Details" however, there are a few rare conditions when the "Details" string might not exist at that location in the array, in which case, I need the loop to look out for "Customer" which would be next. The loop needs to terminate once it hits any of these conditions, as the entire name would have been formatted and passed into the string at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `&&`, not `||`. Otherwise, the condition is *never* not met and the loop won't end.

Simple explanation: For the first piece to be false, `custDet[i]` must equal `"Details"`. But if that's the case then `custDet[i] != "Customer"` will be true, and the loop will continue. For all other values of `custDet[i]`, `custDet[i] != "Details"` will be true and the loop will continue.